# Setting div background image

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I have below div:

```
<div id="MyDiv" style="background-image: " + '@Url.Content("~/images/MyImave.gif")'></div>
```

and I am try to set the background image dynamically by performing:

```
$('#MyDiv').prop("background-image", '@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")');
```

but it is not working, no image is found...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#MyDiv').css("background-image", '@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")');
```

`.css()` is used to set CSS properties in `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method here like:-

```
$('#MyDiv').css("background-image", '@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")');
```

as `.css( propertyName, value )` is used to set one or more CSS properties for elements.

while [`.prop( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) is used to set one or more DOM properties for the elements like selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, etc.